# listings in beamer broken

Tags: beamer, listings

Using this minimal document, I get a `Missing } inserted` error:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{listings}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{title}
  \begin{lstlisting}[language={[LaTeX]TeX}]
    \begin{frame}
      Hello World
    \end{frame} 
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It goes away, if I delete the `\end{frame}` line inside the listing.

I'm quite puzzled. I tried pdflatex (without fontspec) and lualatex.

Comment: This is nothing to do with `listings` or `fontspc`: perhaps edit to make this more general? (We don't have an obvious dupe.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue here is that you can't reliably pick up `\end{frame}` as verbatim content inside a frame which *itself* ends `\end{frame}`. The recommended approach is to use an environment with an alternative name:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}

\newenvironment{Frame}
{\begin{frame}[fragile,environment=Frame]}
{\end{frame}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Frame}
  \frametitle{title}
  \begin{lstlisting}[language={[LaTeX]TeX}]
    \begin{frame}
      Hello World
    \end{frame} 
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{Frame}

\end{document}
```

(One can imagine complex parsing arrangements which try to work this out, but they look horrible and not that reliable.)

Comment: Remember that actually illustrating how use `beamer` is pretty rare as a use case, so the fact this one use needs an alternative approach is probably not so bad.

Comment: This worked last year (TL 2016 at beginning of October). Now it's broken, now meaning TL 2016 frozen as well as TL 2017.

Comment: Something, somewhere changed. This woraround was not necessary before.

Comment: @MaxNoe 'Broken' isn't quite what I'd call it, more 'changed' ;) The problem comes from the fact that some people indent `\end{frame}` generally. You can only make the code in the question work  if you require that a 'real' `\end{frame}` starts a line _and_ that one that is in a verbatim situation doesn't. There are then interactions with various other things (tabs, _etc._). More detail in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/326: notice that _any_ fragile usage has an issue if I don't allow spaces, whereas it's only documenting `\end{frame}` that is problematic if I do.

Comment: @MaxNoe Also https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/360